# Windows Mobile 6.5 and webbrowser

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5

I have an application developed for Windows CE with compact framework 2.0. in c#, Which opens a website developed by the company I work for, using the webbrowser component Component Palette Microsoft. The site uses jquery and javascript. The application works correctly with all operating features of the site without any problem. I need to create the same application for windows mobile 6.5.

I did a pilot project only exchanging plataform (right button on the project-> Change Target Platform ... -> Change to Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK). The result was as follows:

- The application can not load load libraries jQuery, error out of memory when starting the application and some buttons on the site have problem in its functioning. If I comment the libraries of the site, the error disappears and the buttons work correctly, but the jquery site does not work.
- The same application shows different behaviors in versions of windows mobile 6.5 classic and professional.
- If I open the same site, which is opened by the application, in both internet explorer (Windows Mobile 6.5 Windows Mobile 6.5 Classic and Professional) the site works correctly.

So, I have the following questions:

- The application needs work for windows mobile 6.5 classic and professional.
  Thus the project created (SDK) should be the same?
- The Framework utlizado should be compact 2.0 or should I use the compact 3.5?
- Is there any solution to control memory windows mobile 6.5 to avoid
  the out of memory error in IE?
- Is there any alternative to the Microsoft webbrowser component?
- What is the engine used by Microsoft webbrowser component? It would be the default browser installed on Windows Mobile? Can I exchange it?

Graciously

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can use two different IE engines as browser component: a PIE (old wm2003, IE6 compatible) one and a IE6 one (internet explorer MOBILE >=6.1.4, IEM6).

There is also a registry key to switch IEM6 to PIE mode (HKLM/.../Security/MSHTML=1).

The IE used in Windows CE was always more compatible to the desktop IE6 than any IE on Windows Mobile. Although most OEMs simply include the MS example brower called iesample.

I fear you cannot control the memory used but you can improve the memory footprint of your application by moving all code to a library and just call the functions inside that lib. Code run from lib will be handled different by WM than code run from exe: http://robtiffany.com/memmaker-for-the-net-compact-framework/

Windows Mobile Pro and Classic should behave the same in regards of the browser as long as they are based on the same WM build.

Possibly you can show which browser component you are exactly using.

What I can say is that the CE browser component and the new IEM6 browser component will be different.

Comment: Josep how I can change the engine of IE on Windows Mobile as its explanation?

Comment: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238382/windows-mobile-6-5-professional/17241684#17241684 about HKLM\Security\Internet Explorer\MSHTML=0