# Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a problem with windows mobile 6.5 professional. Developed an application that runs on windows mobile 6.5 classic, opening a website from webbrowser.
In Professional website works correctly in IE, but not working javascript / jquery in my application with webbrowser.
I found it strange the contents of the request agent (Request.UserAgent) from the Professional: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible, MSIE 6.0, Windows CE; IEMobile 7:11)

When the Classic appears the following result:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible, MSIE 6.0, Windows NT 5.1, Windows Phone 6.5.3.5

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Well, you've put the tag information in your subject line (which you shouldn't do - it belongs in the tags), and seem to have forgotten to ask a question. :-) Can you [edit] your post and change the subject line to something more meaningful, and clarify the problem and ask us a question we can answer? Thanks.

Comment: @RafaelTriani What exactly is not working.  If its code then we need the code.

Comment: @Ramhound Do not execute the javascript / jquery on the website when I run my aplication with webbrowser.

Answer (score 6):

I recently stumbled upon the same issue. JavaScript works in IE but not in my C# webbrowser component.

The solution was to check HKLM\Security\Internet Explorer\MSHTML registry key. It must be 0 to allow javascript inside webbrowser! Now my code checks and changes this reg key to zero (if not alreday 0) and then calls InitializeComponents().

The key will change the behaviour of the webbrowser in another way too: the arrow keys now do not move the focus from link to link but they scroll the webbrowser view.

Hope that helps you too.

EDIT: here is a code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebBrowser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    public Form1()
    {
        checkMSHTML(0);
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;
    }

    private void toolBar1_ButtonClick(object sender, ToolBarButtonClickEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Button.ImageIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                webBrowser1.Url = new Uri( "http://192.168.128.5/www");
                break;
            case 1:
                this.Close();
                break;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// check and change MSHTML rendering engine
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="iVal">0 = use new IE6 engine, enable JavaScript
    /// 1 = use old PIE engine</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool checkMSHTML(int iVal)
    {
        bool bRet = false;
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Security\Internet Explorer",true);
        if (rKey != null)
        {
            int iMSHTML = (int) rKey.GetValue("MSHTML");
            if (iMSHTML != iVal)
            {
                rKey.SetValue("MSHTML", iVal, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                rKey.Flush();
                rKey.Close();
                bRet = true;
            }
            else
            {
                rKey.Close();
                bRet = true;
            }
        }
        return bRet;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Josef you can post an example of how to do this in C #? I started programming on Windows Mobile a few days and do not have much experience.

Ty for u comentary and help me.