# Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional Font Size doesn't work

Tags: css, font-size, windows-mobile-6.5, registrykey

I have developed an application that uses the native microsoft WebBroswer. I have the following problem, the application opens a website, also developed where I work, and the browser does not support changing the font size (By css for example). I tested the same application on another mobile applications (Windows CE and Windows Mobile 6.0) and it works.
Someone, please, know how to force the device to accept the change font size? By windows registry keys for example.

Answer (score 1):

WM6.5 comes with new Internet Explorer Mobile (IEM) >=6.1.4. This browser is different to the included browser of WM6.1 and before and all the time the browsers on Windows Mobile are very different to browsers on Windows CE.

This new browser tries to re-render the pages optimized for mobile view. There are various settings, if you look at the browsers menu. In example Mobile contra Desktop view, font size setable to small/medium/large etc. All these settings change the view of the page. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416418.aspx

I assume best compatibility should be using Desktop mode.

Further on there is one registry setting that makes IEM behave totally different: HKLM\Security\MSHTML:DWORD[0|1], see also [Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238382/windows-mobile-6-5-professional). Changing the setting makes IEM to behave like the 'old' Pocket Internet Explorer (PIE). PIE does not support keybd event handling, PIE shows scroll bars for larger pages etc. PIE is less compatible to desktop explorer (IE6) and than IEM.

Further on, the page content and design, ie META TAG viewport and others, may prevent IEM to show what you like.

You see, there is not one single possible cause.

More IEM settings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415465.aspx