# Is it possible to use the .NET CF 2.0 browser in a .NET CF 3.5 windows mobile app?

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am working on a Windows Mobile 6.5.3 app using .NET Compact Framework 2.0. I use a webbrowser control to display a barcode, using a jQuery lib.
I have just upgraded my project to .NET CF 3.5, and the browser embedded in the webbrowser control has changed (loading bar at the bottom, large scrollbar etc).
The problem is that my lib does not work anymore on this new browser. Is it possible somehow to use the old browser in the webbrowser control ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great trick in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238382/windows-mobile-6-5-professional/17241684#17241684).
This is a solution given by @josef :

```
/// <summary>
/// check and change MSHTML rendering engine
/// </summary>
/// <param name="iVal">0 = use new IE6 engine, enable JavaScript
/// 1 = use old PIE engine</param>
/// <returns></returns>
bool checkMSHTML(int iVal)
{
    bool bRet = false;
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Security\Internet Explorer",true);
    if (rKey != null)
    {
        int iMSHTML = (int) rKey.GetValue("MSHTML");
        if (iMSHTML != iVal)
        {
            rKey.SetValue("MSHTML", iVal, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            rKey.Flush();
            rKey.Close();
            bRet = true;
        }
        else
        {
            rKey.Close();
            bRet = true;
        }
    }
    return bRet;
}
```